# Не могу прочитать List<объект>

Tags: java, json, gson

Имеется JSON запрос который я получаю со стороны сервера

```
{
  "status":200,
  "result":
    {
      "DATE":"2018-08-20 09:44:14",
      "REQUEST_METHOD":"GET",
      "IP_ADDRESS":"192.168.100.149",
      "COUNTRY_CODE":"RU",
      "CONTROLLER":"mobile",
      "ACTION":"check",
      "PARAMETERS":
        {
          "login":"admin",
          "pass":"admin"
        },
      "SECRET":[
        {
          "USER":"1"
        }
      ],
      "OPERATING_METHOD":"OBJECT_ORIENTED"
    }
}
```

Мне нужно со стороны Java извлечь "USER".

С помощью сервиса `http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/` создал обработчики - геттеры и сеттеры на этот запрос.

Результат с USER пытаюсь извлечь следующим образом

```
List<SECRET> data = category.getResult().getSECRET();
Object[] massive = new Object[data.size()];
data.toArray(massive);

for(Object v : massive)
   System.out.println(v);
```

В консоле выходит следующие

```
I/System.out: com.cnn.portal.mobileapi.app.SECRET@fb47c37
```

Помогите мне разобрать это массив правильно.

Comment: У вас в консоли выводится результат `toString` для `Object`, который возвращает такое: `return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());`. А что вы ожидаете там увидеть?

Comment: Ожидал увидеть чему равен ключ 'USER'

Comment: @РишатГайсин у вас есть объект `SECRET` зачем тут вообще нужен `Object`? У `SECRET` есть геттер для юзера, его и используйте. в цикле.

Comment: @Tsyklop когда обращаюсь к secret.getUSER() выводит: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String ru.mobileapi.app.SECRET.getUSER()' on a null object reference. Получается что он вообще ничего не получает этот геттер?

Comment: @РишатГайсин ошибка говорит что вы вызываете метод у объекта который, грубо говоря, null. то бишь не имеет ссылки на объект в памяти.

Comment: @Tsyklop окей, я разобрался как дойти до массива SECRET с помощью gson'а. Выглядит строка следующим образом Log.i("GSON", category.result.sECRET); но как открыть массив SECRET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, хотя не со всем понимаю почему именно так работает. РЕШЕНИЕ: Log.i("GSON", "Результат: " + category.result.sECRET.get(0).getUSER());

Answer (score 0):

Где-то так

```
for (USER u : data)
   System.out.println(u.getUSER());
```

Comment: Я разобрался как дойти до массива SECRET с помощью gson'а. Выглядит строка следующим образом Log.i("GSON", category.result.sECRET); но как открыть массив SECRET?

Comment: Откуда берется такой код?